# How to implement secure Master / Super Password authentication in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

How to implement a mechanism that will allow to log in as any user using a specific password (a so called master password or super password) that is valid for any log in?

This is needed for administrative and support purposes.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a master password you should not hardcode the password in the source code and use the full authentication security that Devise gives. To do this you can add this code in your models:

```
class User
  ...
  # enables a Master Password check
  def valid_password?(password)
    return true if valid_master_password?(password)
    super
  end

  # WARNING: Master User password changes require an application process restart
  DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL = 'master@somedomain.com' # config # SUGESTION: Move to an app configuration file
  DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.first(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL) # cache
  DEFAULT_ENCRYPTED_MASTER_PASSWORD = DEFAULT_MASTER_USER.try(:encrypted_password) # cache
  # Code duplicated from the Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password? method
  # TODO: Propose Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password?(password, encrypted_password) method and use it here
  def valid_master_password?(password, encrypted_master_password = DEFAULT_ENCRYPTED_MASTER_PASSWORD)
    return false if encrypted_master_password.blank?
    bcrypt_salt = ::BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_master_password).salt
    bcrypt_password_hash = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{password}#{self.class.pepper}", bcrypt_salt)
    Devise.secure_compare(bcrypt_password_hash, encrypted_master_password)
  end
  ...
end
```

This should be as secure as your master (super, admin) users password. This will "only" give the master user more power - the power to login as anybody using his password.

The `valid_master_password?` method can be also used to setup master passwords for groups of users etc. For example for the admin users of organizations:

```
class User
  ...
  # enables a Master Password check
  def valid_password?(password)
    return true if valid_master_password?(password) or 
                   valid_master_password?(password, self.organization.admin_user.encrypted_password)
    super
  end
  ...
end
```

I've also described this in the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Configure-a-master-password).

If you need a master password only in development then it is easier to use this code:

```
class User
  ...
  def valid_password?(password)
    return true if Rails.env.development? and password == "THE_MASTER_PASSWORD"
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't there a problem in loading the DEFAULT_MASTER_USER as you haven't defined the User relation at the moment you make the query?

Comment: @OleksandrKruk good question. This code does not give me any problems. Why does this work could be a good case to ask for on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @SzymonJeż here i am getting error " can't convert Hash into Integer

 in " on this line   DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.first(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL) # cache

Comment: This works fine in development. But in production, with Mongodb with SSL support, the deployment breaks down:
MONGODB | SSL handshake failed. MongoDB may not be configured with SSL support.

Answer (score 2):

I'm implementing this in production, but had to change this line:

`DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.first(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL)`

to

`DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.find_by(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL)`

Since it's not looking up the user by the id, but rather the email address.

Answer (score 0):

I respond lately, but I've been unable to use any of the solution proposed.
My answer to the problem was far simpler but it do the trick.

Put your master password in your application credentials, then use this in your user model :

```
def valid_password?(password)
  return true if password == Rails.application.credentials.dig(:master_password)
  super
end
```